# Camera Permission denied for HTML5 QR Code scanner in solar2D Native NewWebView

Tags: asp.net, lua, android-camera, qr-code, solar2d

I made a Web App in asp.net which scans QR Codes. I used jquery plugin [minhazav qr code reader](https://blog.minhazav.dev/research/html5-qrcode.html). It works fine with all the browsers like chrome, safari, opera etc.

Now I wanted to convert it to mobile app and I chose solar2D platform.

I used Native NewWebView to load my Web App. Everything works fine but when I try to open scanner page [QR Code Reader](https://www.trubuy.in/Scanner.aspx), it shows permission denied. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it.

Why this works with chrome and other browsers but not in native.newWebView?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6" id="reader" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"></div>
<div class="form-group floating-form-group">
<input type="text" id="txtLink" class="form-control floating-input" disabled="disabled" />                        
</div>
<a href="javascript:void" class="mt-4 btn btn-info btn-block btn-lg btnProceed">Proceed</a>
```

**JS**

```
function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) 
{           
     $("#txtLink").val(decodedText);
     $(".btnProceed").attr("href", decodedText);
}
function onScanError(errorMessage) {
     alert('Some Error');
}
var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner("reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 200 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess, onScanError);
```

**SOLAR 2D**

**BUILD SETTINGS**

```
settings = {
    
    android =
    {
        
        usesPermissions =
        {            
            "android.permission.INTERNET",
            "android.permission.CALL_PHONE",
            "android.permission.CAMERA",
            "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE",
            "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
            "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
            
        },
        usesFeatures =
        {           
            { name = "android.hardware.camera", required=true },
            { name = "android.hardware.location", required = false },
            { name = "android.hardware.location.gps", required = false },
            { name = "android.hardware.location.network", required = false },
        },  
    },


    orientation = {
        default = "portrait"
        
    },  
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you,

I tried to force camera permissions once the app loads. It shows a prompt that, this app requires camera access to capture photos or record videos. But this didn't work either.

```
local function appPermissionsListener( event )
    for k,v in pairs( event.grantedAppPermissions ) do
        if ( v == "Camera" ) then
            print( "Camera permission granted!" )
        end
    end
end
 
local options =
{
    appPermission = "Camera",
    urgency = "Critical",
    listener = appPermissionsListener,
    rationaleTitle = "Camera access required",
    rationaleDescription = "Camera access is required to take photos. Re-request now?",
    settingsRedirectTitle = "Alert",
    settingsRedirectDescription = "Without the ability to take photos, this app cannot properly function. Please grant camera access within Settings."
}

native.showPopup( "requestAppPermission", options )
```

Now I am completely clueless.